# getting error error TypeError: Member "isContract" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, library

Using Solidity 0.4.17, I have defined a simple library at ./Addresses.sol

```
     function isContract(address _base) external pure returns(bool) {
    assembly {
        _r := gt(extcodesize(_base), 0)
     }
   }
 }
```

Now I am trying to use it in a contract at ./AddressesTests.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import "./Addresses.sol";

contract AddressesTests {
using Addresses for address;

function testIsContract() public {
    //error  TypeError: Member "isContract" not found or not visible 
  //after argument-dependent lookup in address payable.
    assert(address(this).isContract());
    assert(!msg.sender.isContract());
   }
 }
```

I get the error

```
   TypeError: Member "isContract" not found or not visible after 
   argument-dependent lookup in address payable.
    assert(!msg.sender.isContract());
            ^-------------------^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tried `address(msg.sender).isContract()`?

Comment: try to declare an `address` variable , assign `msg.sender` to it and then try same.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: See the answer from similar question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103681/76945